# how to find overall average memory usage and cpu percent of a local machine in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, average, cpu, cpu-usage

I have tried using htop and top commands to find the average CPU usage and memory usage.It is giving me the usage at that particular time but i have to find this averages over the time my API is running,so how do i achieve that?.

Answer (score 0):

The most common method for this is an app that polls SNMP on your box and records the values in a database.  There are a variety of tools like MRTG, Nagios etc that can do this.  But keep in mind these still are a instantaneous snapshot of the performance albeit many single snapshots that you view graphically. The more granular the timeframe, the smoother the curve.